# rails4, mongoid, find GTE or LTE Query using custom model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Using Rails4, mongoid

I define total_count

```
def total_likes
   user_like + customer_like
end
```

And I find gte or lte using model custom method, total_count

How I type in Controller?

```
class ImageClip

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include ModelHelper


  field :is_visible, type: Integer, default: 0
  field :is_deleted, type: Integer, default: 0
  field :is_hide, type: Integer, default: 0
  field :user_id, type: Integer
  field :user_likes, type: Integer, default: 0
  field :customer_like, type: Integer, default: 0


  mount_uploader :media_url, MuseUploader


  def total_likes
    likes + amusing_likes
  end
```

And I Find

```
    ImageClip.gte(total_likes: 10)
```

---

I Found Solution

```
    ImageClip.where("(this.user_likes + this.customer_like) > #{LIKE_GTE}")
```

---

Comment: Please mention correctly what you want to write in your controller!

Comment: @RubyOnRails I add my ImageClip model file Contents. And I find greate than or Equal 10 using custom method, total_likes

Comment: I found solution and modify question XD